# How to run an Azure Powershell Task in Azure DevOps Pipeline using a Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I want to run an Azure Powershell task in my DevOps pipeline that access and modifies my Azure resources. For this task, I need to select either my Azure subscription or provide a Service Connection in the highlighted dropdown.
[image]

Is there any way to run this script using my previously setup service principal (by using its Application ID, Tenant ID, App Secret and Subscription ID)? Or can I use a Powershell task and somehow do a "az login" using the above service principal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can. Just navigate to the `Project Settings` -> `Service connections` -> `New service connection` -> `Azure Resource Manager` -> `Service principal (manual)`.

[image]

Then you can fix the values with the existing service principal -> `verify and save`.

[image]

In the Azure Powershell Task, simply select the service connection.

[image]

Comment: Actually the answer is pretty straightforward. I wonder how it slipped my mind. I accept this as the answer.